# Using reflection to set properties for wcf datacontract

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection

I have a wcf service, dynamically calling wcf service through wsdl file at client. Now I want to set the properties of a method inside my wcf service. I had properties which are complextypes, and In each complex type I had 30 to 4o complex types.  I cannot touch the service, only thing is using reflection assing values to the service datacontract and using methodInfo.Invoke(pass constructed object array).  Client will pass input parameters for datacontract in dictionary.  Is recursion need to navigate through inner classes of a complextype and set values.
      **Sample Code:**

```
 public CompositeType GetTestDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite, string str, int i,EmployeeIn obj)
 {
        ///code here
 }
  **DataContract for CompositeType**
      [DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";
    EmployeeIn employeeValue;
    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public EmployeeIn EmploValue
    {
        get { return employeeValue; }
        set { employeeValue = value; }
    }
}  
   EmployeeIn Class
       [DataContract]
public class EmployeeIn
{
    bool UserIsOnline = true;
    string UserName = "DANGER";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return UserIsOnline; }
        set { UserIsOnline = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return UserName; }
        set { UserName = value; }
    }
}
```

Using reflection I want to set these properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for setting properties via Reflection with property name provided by string:

```
void SetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyPath, object value)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo currentProperty = null;
    string[] pathSteps = propertyPath.Split('/');
    object currentObj = obj;
    for (int i = 0; i < pathSteps.Length; ++i)
    {
        Type currentType = currentObj.GetType();
        string currentPathStep = pathSteps[i];
        var currentPathStepMatches = Regex.Match(currentPathStep, @"(\w+)(?:\[(\d+)\])?");
        currentProperty = currentType.GetProperty(currentPathStepMatches.Groups[1].Value);
        int arrayIndex = currentProperty.PropertyType.IsArray ? int.Parse(currentPathStepMatches.Groups[2].Value) : -1;
        if (i == pathSteps.Length - 1)
        {
            currentProperty.SetValue(currentObj, value, arrayIndex > -1 ? new object[] { arrayIndex } : null);
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentProperty.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {
                currentObj = (currentProperty.GetValue(currentObj) as Array).GetValue(arrayIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                currentObj = currentProperty.GetValue(currentObj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this function to set properties like, for example:

```
SetPropertyValue(someClass, "SomeInt", 4);
SetPropertyValue(someClass, "ArrayProperty[5]/Char", (char)2);
SetPropertyValue(someClass, "TestField", new SomeOtherClass());
```

Comment: Hi Konrad, I had written my code, please provide your inputs,

Comment: @user3001558 update your answer according to usage of my function if you found it helpful and want some clarifications.

Comment: Thanks, but I can find my code and your code in the thread, shall I send compressed code file to your id, please provide your mail-id.  we are working on POC integrating 50 diffr. wcf and web services. To provide generic sol.

Comment: @user3001558 for completeness, it would be much better to show your efforts here.